# I want to use datetime modul utcfromtimestamp method but its not work in Ninja-IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-import

I want to use `datetime` module `utcfromtimestamp` method but its not work in Ninja-IDE. How I can solve my problem?

My code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
print (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(130130301))
```

And Ninja-IDE 2.3 writes this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\datetime.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(130130301))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utcfromtimestamp'
```

I installed Python 3.4 and  setup the path in preferences.

Comment: read [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You named your file `datetime.py`, and Python imported that instead of the standard library `datetime`:

```
File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\datetime.py", line 3, in <module>
#                           ^^^^^^^^
```

So the first `datetime` is your module, the second `datetime` a global in your module that references itself, and your module doesn't itself have a `utcfromtimestamp` global.

Rename your file to something else.